# Get result from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am calling a stored procedure but I can't save the return value coming from stored procedure.

My code is:

```
var data = db.Database.SqlQuery<rig>("exec rig_create @cid @name @crane @bop", param1, param2, param3, param4).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am getting the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '@name'.'

Thanks

Comment: What does running rig_create in SSMS output?  For your code to work it should output a single resultset with columns matching the table that 'rig' is mapped to.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use commas between parameters `exec rig_create @cid, @name, @crane ...`

Comment: i tried giving error System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'omciModel.rig'. A member of the type, 'id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same nam

Comment: @Rohitsharma it is a different story, I guess I have answered your question.

Comment: I just added comma as u suggested but i am getting this error now

Answer (score 0):

Add commas between your parameters `@cid @name @crane @bop`

It should be like this----> `@cid, @name, @crane, @bop`

Comment: i tried giving error System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'omciModel.rig'. A member of the type, 'id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.'